# What are recommended values for block size, buffercount and maxtransfer size for Ola backups to Azure?

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren, azure-vm, azure-blob-storage

I have SQL servers running on onprem and Azure VM hardware.

The backups write to a file share located on a network VM.

I am wanting to change the backup destination to Azure blob storage.

For this I have created an Azure storage account and tested the Ola backup script with credentials (account key/identity and also with shared access signature).

Is want some guidance on what is recommended values to use for the following:

1. Block size
2. Buffer count
3. Max transfer size

I understand that the block blob has a 200GB file limit and this is OK for me as my compressed backups come to under 110GB.

I understand that Azure blob has a limitation of 50000 blocks * 4MB maxtransfersize.

What is the idea values to use so that I don't hit the above limit.

Answer (score 1):

- [Official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sqlcat/backing-up-a-vldb-to-azure-blob-storage)

> Conclusion: If using Backup to URL to create striped backups of large databases (over 48 GB per stripe), specify MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304 and BLOCKSIZE = 65536 in the BACKUP statement.

- [Also useful](https://gist.github.com/scheffler/7edd40f430235aab651fadcc7d191a89)

You can stripe your backup over multiple files to support larger databases if needed.

Comment: I'm not using stripped backups. My compressed backups size is 110GB.

Comment: What exactly is block and Max transfer size. So if block size is X and transfer size is Y, then does it mean that SQL will create multiple X blocks until the total size reaches Y and then upload it to the Azure blob storage?

Comment: The BLOCKSIZE and MAXTRANSFERSIZE have been around before BACKUP to URL and are documented here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
They are not used that often but are needed now to support larger backups on Azure DB.